# Delay in visa process

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia

I had applied for visitor visa to Australia and it's still in process while I already have my New Zealand student visa and traveling to NZ for the first time, does it matters if I get a visa for Australia and I don't fly there because I'll be already busy with my studies in New Zealand by then

Comment: If you are certain that you won't use the Australian visa, ask Australia to cancel it (or withdraw the application, if it hasn't been granted yet).It saves *them* the time and money to process your visa, and *you* demonstrate that you're on top of your paperwork.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asking whether there would be any adverse consequences if, after being granted a visitor visa for Australia, you do not use it.

Probably not.  This is especially true because you have a reasonable explanation for not travelling to Australia, namely that the visa was granted after your intended period of travel, and you were unable to change your plans because of your studies.